# How to set up an event listener without an anonymous function? (not losing scope)

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, electron, anonymous-function

This is quite a basic question I assume, but I haven't found out how to solve this problem on my own. Suppose I have a React file in which I set up a listener:

```
ipcRenderer.on('receiveData', function() {
  console.log("Hello World");
});
```

I am listening for an event sent by electron. The example above works. Whenever the receiveData event is fired, my *anonymous* function logs `Hello World`. Now say I have a different function the same React file, and don't want to fire the anonymous function anymore, but my own. Like so:

```
myOwnFunction() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}

ipcRenderer.on('receiveData', myOwnFunction);
```

I have tried this but it does not work. Here is the whole thing:

```
import React from 'react';
//...
class TextView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                    inputField: '',
                  };
  }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
  }
  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({inputField: e.target.value})
  }


  myOwnFunction() {
    console.log("MY OWN");
  }

  onButtonClick(event) {
    ipcRenderer.send('sendInvite', 1);
    ipcRenderer.on('rightPressed', function(event, arg){ console.log("stuff"+arg); });  //line 34; this works
    ipcRenderer.on('rightPressed', myOwnFunction); //line 35, this does not work

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        //....
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

When the event is emitted, I now get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myOwnFunction is not defined
>       at onButtonClick (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:1286:38)
>       at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:15663:16)
>       at executeDispatch (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:8657:21)
>       at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:8680:5)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:8114:22)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:8125:10)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at forEachAccumulated (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:22170:9)
>       at Object.processEventQueue (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:8330:7)
>       at runEventQueueInBatch (file:///Users/user/Coding/electron-noprebuilt/public/js/bundle.js:15690:18)

Comment: ipcRenderer.on('receiveData',myOwnFunction);

Comment: Can you update your question to show where you want to use `this` and explain what you expect it to be?

Comment: "I seem to lose scope" — Your function doesn't do anything with anything in the current scope. You need to provide a real [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: alright I will do so in a bit.

Comment: … for that matter, your function isn't even syntactically valid.

Comment: It seems that you are not quite sure how the scope works, and as Quention said you are not even using it (explicitly) I would go with andrew's answer and then read about scopes from Mozila or Javascript The Definitive Guide

Comment: Yes, I am not quite sure how scope works, which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Put the word `function` before the function name.  This is a syntax error - nothing more - `function myOwnFunction()...`

Comment: thanks, I will try. just out of curiosity: why does it work with my other React functions but would be a problem for this function?

Comment: Functions will always be declared as `function foo() { }` or `var foo = function() { }`.  Anything else is incorrect syntax and will give a syntax error similar to the one you posted.  This has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the same error

Comment: Show us the scope of your function myOwnFunction

Comment: @Archer In React examples, I never see the `function` keyword in classes.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder — Is your code in a React class? Maybe you should provide a [mcve] instead of a fragment of code from the middle of your file.

Comment: ^^ That.  What you've posted is Javascript.  Your question is far from complete so we can't help you.

Comment: sorry about that. i asked a question about React/electron previously but did not get any answers, so I thought I'd just ask for javascript, but well, that didn't work out. I edited it now.

Comment: @Quentin edited. does this look better?

Comment: It looks better. It would help if we know which line was line 35, and I still don't know what scope has to do with this.

Comment: remove your extra "}"

Comment: ipcRenderer.on('rightPressed', myOwnFunction }); in this line

Comment: Start using an IDE to avoid these kind of errors, at least they will help you in identifying them.

Comment: Change line 35 to this... `ipcRenderer.on('rightPressed', this.myOwnFunction);`

Comment: I then get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myOwnFunction' of null
    at onButtonClick`

Comment: @GeorgeWelder, can you setup a snippet here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrow function` it will bind the `context`. To call any `function` that is present in same `class` we need to use `this` keyword. Like this:

`this.myOwnFunction()   //it will call the 'myOwnFunction' function`

Write it like this using `arrow function`:

```
ipcRenderer.on('receiveData', () => {    //use arrow function
     this.myOwnFunction()
});
```

**Note**: Above code will work, but make sure you `bind` the method `onButtonClick`.

Comment: why do the arrow function suggestions get downvoted? It would be interesting for me to understand why this solution is not a good one?

Comment: i also wanted to know why downvote :)  btw try this it should work.

Comment: I assume that someone downvoted you (and others) because you didn't understand the problem OP has. Arrow function or bind is not a solution, or rather a solution to different problem, not what OP has.

Comment: @MayankShukla This actually worked for me! Thank you so much! I guess my first error was the wrong error, and the fault was actually with scope. Amazing you did not delete this.